# How can I make two 'Point Graphs' in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make two point graphs that have one color per variable.

[image]

This is what I have so far.

How can I change the colors of upper points?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
ggplot(data=mydata3, aes(x = A, y = B, fill = B)) +
  geom_point(stat = "identity", aes(color = B))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text( face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 20, color = "black")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = B), size = 5, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack") +
  geom_point(data=mydata2, aes(x= A, y = B, fill = 원격.수업.방식))+
  geom_point(stat = "identity", aes(color = A))+ 
  geom_text(aes(label = B), size = 5, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack")
```

Comment: In your second geom_point `geom_point(data=mydata2, aes(x= A, y = B, fill = 원격.수업.방식))` your are mapping on fill instead of on color. Hence with default shape you get black points.

Comment: thx I fix it :)

Comment: then how to get label of upper one such as below one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's why stefan said, but I thought I'd put an answer so that other people will know where to look.

The problem is that you're using `fill` instead of `color` or `colour` on the `geom_point()` for the upper points. Therefore:

```
ggplot(data=mydata3, aes(x = A, y = B, fill = B)) +
  geom_point(stat = "identity", aes(color = B))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text( face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 20, color = "black")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = B), size = 5, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack") +
  geom_point(data=mydata2, aes(x= A, y = B, color = 원격.수업.방식))+
  geom_point(stat = "identity", aes(color = A))+ 
  geom_text(aes(label = B), size = 5, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "stack")
```